# how can i ignore a specific test within a class or package

Tags: jenkins, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I tried using the following:
Dtest=acceptance.priceadjustment.**,!acceptance.priceadjustment.BasePriceAdjustmentTest,!acceptance.priceadjustment.OpportunityPriceAdjustmentIndexTest,!acceptance.priceadjustment.PriceAdjustmentOverrideTest

but this did not work, all tests within priceadjustent class still executed.

tried Dtest=acceptance.priceadjustment.**,!acceptance.priceadjustment.BasePriceAdjustmentTest,!acceptance.priceadjustment.OpportunityPriceAdjustmentIndexTest,!acceptance.priceadjustment.PriceAdjustmentOverrideTest

expecting to have !acceptance.priceadjustment.BasePriceAdjustmentTest,!acceptance.priceadjustment.OpportunityPriceAdjustmentIndexTest,!acceptance.priceadjustment.PriceAdjustmentOverrideTest ignored

but this did not work, all tests within priceadjustent class still executed.